# Linear Independence??

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I had to verify that
$\langle t , t^2 \rangle$ and $\langle t^3 , t^4 \rangle$
are linearly independent. I worked it out by finding the determinant of the two vectors and the answer was 0 which means they are linearly dependent. Can anyone explain to me where I messed up when doing this problem? thanks

Comment: What is $t$? What vector space are we working in? Can you show us your calculation of the determinant?

Comment: Why do you think you messed up? Note that $t^2\cdot \langle t,t^2\rangle=\langle t^3,t^4\rangle$.

Comment: I assume that since the question is asking me to verify linear independence the vectors are linearly independent.

Comment: The problem does not define what t is, but I calculated the determinant by 
ad - bc => (t)($t^4$) - ($t^2$)($t^3$) = 0

Answer (score 1):

To show that $\langle t,t^2\rangle$ and $\langle t^3,t^4\rangle$ are linearly independent, we need to show that $$a\langle t,t^2\rangle+b\langle t^3,t^4\rangle=\langle0,0\rangle\implies\ a=b=0$$ (trivial solution) is the only solution
Indeed. This is true, hence we have proved linear independence